# Guide to understanding the Navision (2013) Database for BI

Tags: database, business-intelligence, microsoft-dynamics

i build reports from small databases. My largest one had around 80 tables. Currently I'm trying to understand the Navision (Cronos) Database.

Is there any guide/ tutorial/ education available for understanding the NAV database concept ?

There are so many tables I don't now where to start... I know about that "about this page" function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's not how it works...NAV is not a database it's a business application which stores data in tables.
You need to sit down with an experienced NAV Professional and and discuss every specific reporting needs.

If you can give me an example i'm happy to point you to the right direction...

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I found the solution myself. There is a product called JetReport that offers a free Database dictionary. Of course each customer has his own database but I just wanted to understand the standard Cronos one. I trust that any NAV underlying database will be similar to the demo.

Comment: Hi, Cool! And yes the (basic system) tables will be the same (name) but you can have different fields (=more fields) in them.